# Fail to plot the 30mins candlebar with candlestick_ohlc in Python

Tags: candlestick-chart

I try to plot the 30mins candlebar with candlestick_ohlc in Python. But it failed and return a weird picture.

[image]
ha_bar is a list with time,open,high,low and close.

```
ha_bar=[(736389.41666666663, 24.317, 25.109, 24.317, 24.29975), 
(736389.4375, 24.308374999999998, 25.529, 25.027750000000001, 
25.027750000000001), (736389.45833333337, 24.668062499999998, 25.977, 
25.543499999999998, 25.543499999999998), (736389.47847222222, 25.10578125, 
25.898, 25.541249999999998, 25.541249999999998), (736389.5625, 
25.323515624999999, 25.818000000000001, 25.454000000000001, 
25.454000000000001)]


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.finance as mpf
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
mpf.candlestick_ohlc(ax, ha_bar,width=0.6)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

how to plot the 30mins candlebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting width=0.001 in mpf.candlestick_ohlc(ax, ha_bar,width=0.6)